# Film about the sun reproducing

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a film when I was very young.

There were a group of people who wake up at the start of the film, one of them woke from a drug induced coma of some kind.

Everyone in the world seems dead apart from them and they discover this is because the sun is reproducing and had emitted a load of deadly rays that only seemed to kill people conscious at the time.

The people in the film have a certain amount of time before this happens again.

Comment: Do you know roughly when you saw it? A decade/year is more helpful than “when I was very young”. Was it colour or black-and-white? Remember any character names?

Comment: I've got my finger poised over the dupe button; [Trying to find a TV show about an event that leaves everyone dead apart from people who died at the moment of the event?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73655/trying-to-find-a-tv-show-about-an-event-that-leaves-everyone-dead-apart-from-peo)...

Comment: @Valorum: Button pushed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This does sound very much like "The Quiet Earth" as @Valorum has said in a comment.

- At the very start of the movie, the main protagonist in TQE wakes up from an attempt at overdosing with pills
- The very few people who are around in the movie had similar experiences
- The protagonist is a scientist who realises something is going on with the sun