# Identify a film (and possibly book) about a scientific incident that makes most of the Earth's population disappear

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is a film that I remember seeing on television, probably in the first half of the 1990s. I recall that it may also have been a book.

Some plot elements that I recall:

- The protagonist, male, wakes up in his bed, and discovers that everybody has disappeared without trace from his neighbourhood.
- The man works at a lab, presumably doing some scientific research.
- He returns to the lab. Whilst in the lab an accident happens that, although not serious, blocks his exit from the lab. He fashions an explosive device that allows him to exit.
- He later discovers that there are other survivors.
- The survivors form a search party to seek others. The protagonist disagrees with this search, but reluctantly takes part. They split up and each search a particular area. However the protagonist does not do his search; instead he is an a lab performing more scientific work into the cause of the incident. When the search leader contacts him by walkie-talkie to ask where he is, he lies, consulting a map to give a street name.
- The finale of the film takes place at the scientific lab where he worked, and he drives a truck at high speed into the lab. At this point another incident occurs, and he wakes up on what appears to be a different planet.

I recall being told that the film was based on a book, and had a different ending - the incident at the finale resulted in the protagonist going back in time to the first incident and re-living it.

Comment: Almost certainly [The Quiet Earth.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73655/trying-to-find-a-tv-show-about-an-event-that-leaves-everyone-dead-apart-from-peo). Repeatedly duplicated on the site :-)

Comment: Aw man, and I thought I'd done a half-decent job of searching the archive. Thanks @Valorum!

Comment: I live and breathe but to serve and help.