# Old sci-fi movie where a guy wakes up naked on his bed and everyone is gone

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched it probably like 35 years ago (perhaps more), don't remember much, but the overall sense never got out of my mind (one of the items that make a great sci-fi story). Never seen the movie again.

The guy wakes up on his bed, fells dizzy, dresses up, walks out, all is quiet. Roams around, sees no one, looks like everyone just vanished while doing everyday stuff. Cars on the streets, things left around, even a newspaper dropped in the floor in the front of a toilet.

> The story goes on, I think he finds a few people, don't remember much, but then he decides to suicide himself, and does so exactly at the time that some strange environmental phenomena happens too. He then awakes again, which hints to the fact that the strange phenomena has already happen before, and that he has already committed suicide before the movie begins, and exactly at the same time the event happens. In fact, all people he finds although the movie seem to have died exactly at the same time of the event, so they kept living in perhaps another parallel dimension.

> But now, he wakes up just to find he's in a completely different planet, an alien world, where another planet, with rings, is rising on the horizon. He then cries out loud and the movie ends.

Not a particularly great production, but something to remember nonetheless. Does anyone ever seen this marvel of sci-fi?

Comment: This is, of course, The Quiet Earth; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73655/trying-to-find-a-tv-show-about-an-event-that-leaves-everyone-dead-apart-from-peo

Comment: Oh, gezzzz, it is! Great and quick answer! Thanks for that! And he's a scientist working on Project Flashlight, "an experiment to create a wireless global energy grid to power military equipment", in a Tesla's like idea. Fantastic, will look to watch it right now!

Comment: Oh... I see it has been asked before... I did a quick search and couldn't find, next time will search more.

Comment: -1 for gratuitous use of spoiler tags.

Comment: @Lexible, hi there, but sorry, I don't get it, shouldn't I have used spoiler tags? Or should use only one? No matter the downvote, I just want to understand better. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all! It has been asked before, so no issue closing it. I really didn't find it on the search. Perhaps we should add a tag "guy-wakes-up-naked-everyone-is-gone" :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like ***[The Quiet Earth](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089869/)*** (1985).

From IMDB:

> A man named Zac Hobson awakens to find himself alone in the world. In a desperate attempt to search for others, he finds only two who have their own agenda.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quiet_Earth_(film)):

> *The Quiet Earth* is a 1985 New Zealand post-apocalyptic science fiction film directed by Geoff Murphy and starring Bruno Lawrence, Alison Routledge and Peter Smith as three survivors of a cataclysmic disaster. It is loosely based on the 1981 science fiction novel of the same name by Craig Harrison. Other sources of inspiration have been suggested: the 1954 novel [*I Am Legend*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Legend_(novel)), [*Dawn of the Dead*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_of_the_Dead_(1978_film)), and especially the 1959 film [*The World, the Flesh and the Devil*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World,_the_Flesh_and_the_Devil_(1959_film)), of which it has been called an unofficial remake.

> 5 July begins as a normal winter morning near Hamilton, New Zealand. At 6:12 a.m., the sun darkens for a moment, and a red light surrounded by darkness is briefly seen.
>
> **Zac Hobson is a scientist employed by Delenco, part of a US-led international consortium working on "Project Flashlight" - an experiment to create a wireless global energy grid to power military equipment. He awakens abruptly; when he turns on his radio, he is unable to receive any transmissions. He gets dressed and drives into the deserted city. Investigating a fire, he discovers the burning wreckage of a passenger jet, but there are no bodies, only empty seats.**
>
> Zac enters his laboratory, but fails to contact any of the other labs around the world. In an underground lab, he discovers the dead body of a colleague at a control panel; a monitor displays the message "Operation Flashlight Complete". The mass disappearance seems to coincide with the moment Flashlight was activated. The lab is suddenly and automatically sealed because of radiation, so he improvises a bomb to escape. He listens to his own voice on a tape recorder describing the project as having "phenomenal destructive potential", then notes: "Zac Hobson, July 5th. One: there has been a malfunction in Project Flashlight with devastating results. Two: it seems I am the only person left on Earth." From this point onward, he refers to the crucial moment and its result as "The Effect".
>
> After a week of vain attempts to contact another human being, Zac moves into a mansion. His mental state begins to deteriorate. He puts on a woman's nightgown and alternates between exhilaration and despair. He assembles cardboard cutouts of famous people (including Adolf Hitler, Elizabeth II, and Pope John Paul II), plays a loud fanfare and cheers from large speakers, and addresses the cutouts from a balcony. He declares himself "President of this Quiet Earth", then goes on a destructive rampage after the power blacks out. He bursts into a church, shoots a statue of Jesus off a crucifix, and announces that he is God. After accidentally crushing an empty pram with an enormous earthmover, he puts the barrel of a shotgun into his mouth, but finally comes to his senses.
>
> Zac settles into a more normal routine. One morning, a young woman named Joanne appears. Zac is attracted to her, and after a few days together they have sex. They scour the city and find a third survivor, a large Māori man named Api. The three determine why they survived: at the instant of The Effect, they were all at the moment of death: Api was being drowned in a fight, Joanne was electrocuted by a faulty hairdryer, and Zac had overdosed on pills in a suicide attempt. He had realized the experiment posed serious dangers and was guilt-ridden for not speaking out.
>
> A love triangle develops, but Zac is more concerned about his scientific observations: universal physical constants are changing, such as the value of electron charge, causing the Sun's output to fluctuate. Zac fears The Effect will occur again and decides to destroy the Delenco facility in an attempt to stop it. The three put aside their personal conflicts and drive a truckload of explosives to the installation, only to be stopped at the perimeter when Zac detects dangerous levels of ionising radiation emanating from the plant. He says that he will go to town to retrieve a remote control device to send the truck into the facility.
>
> While Zac is gone, Joanne and Api have sex. Afterward, Api tells Joanne that he will sacrifice himself by driving the truck; he doubts that Zac's device will be capable of controlling the vehicle. They then hear the truck and realise that Zac did not go to town after all. He drives the truck onto the weakened roof of the underground portion of the laboratory, which collapses. Just as the effect reaches a maximum, he triggers the explosives.
>
> **Once again, a bright red light is seen surrounded by a dark tunnel. Zac awakens to find himself lying face down on a beach at twilight. There are strange cloud formations, resembling waterspouts, rising out of the ocean. He walks to the water's edge, glancing momentarily at his tape recorder, as an enormous ringed planet slowly appears over the horizon.**

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, for sure! I guess @Valorum answered it in the comments, but anyway you provided a complete answer very quickly. Don't want to step on anyone's toes but I guess you're right.